# Why were these creatures the allies to the Elves in the MTV adaptation of The Shannara Chronicles?

Tags: shannara, shannara-chronicles, elfstones-of-shannara

In the recent TV series *The Shannara Chronicles*, season one is a *loose* adaptation of *The Elfstones of Shannara*. In that series,

> The Gnomes(!) became the *only* major allies to the Elves

Yet in the book,

> "Troll and Dwarf, Elf and Man" (p.442) were the only races allied, the Gnomes specifically were *not* called:
> "No messenger had been sent to the Gnomes [by Eventine, King of the Elves]. It would have been pointless to do so. The Gnomes were a tribal race. They did not answer to a single ruler or governing council. Their chieftains and their seers were their leaders, all constantly feuding with one another. Bitter and disgruntled since their defeat at Tyrsis [in *The Sword of Shannara*], the Gnomes had not mixed in the affairs of the other races in the fifty years that had since passed. It was hardly reasonable to expect that they should choose to do so now" (p.277).

**So is there recorded anywhere by MTV or Terry Brooks (who did have part in the TV series adaptation) why these creatures were chosen as the allies, rather than even *one* of the others that might have been and remained more faithful to the book?**

NOTE: I enjoyed the book immensely, and generally the TV series also (some exceptions to some content). But the series story was only enjoyable by setting aside my love for the book, as the book's story had much more depth in both the characters and conflict, both in Arborlon and on the quest. **So while I realize *much* changed between book and series, I am seeking here for an out of world reasoning as to why this particular change.**

Comment: When I watched the series, I understood it to take place about 30 years after the end of *Elfstones*. Something about when Allanon came out of his Druid Sleep (or whatever it was) and what was said at that point in the TV-series which led me to believe that.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2: No, it is very much loosely based on the _Elfstones_ directly, as both book and series are entirely about the same, generally, quest (for Wil and Amberle) and conflict (Elves vs. Demons).

Comment: No worries. I'll have to go back and watch again so I understand.